# Tkinter grouping buttons and lables

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a GUI where you specify a bunch of files for later processing (commandline parsing a dozen files is just a PITA).

So now I want to group a lable and a button for better readability.

I've tried something like that:

```
DC1_path_label = Label(window_fine_DC, text = "Please specify the path of DC 1:", relief=RAISED)
DC1_B = Tkinter.Button(window_fine_DC, textvariable = DC_path1, command = setDC1)
DC2_path_label = Label(window_fine_DC, text="Please specify the path of DC 2:", relief=RAISED)
DC2_B = Tkinter.Button(window_fine_DC, textvariable=DC_path2, command=setDC2)

DC1_path_label.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
DC1_B.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
DC2_path_label.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
DC2_B.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
```

but it seems to have no effect, also paddings dont work that great either, since those go in all directions equally.

And while we are at it, is there a more elegant way to change a window than closing the old one, and opening a new?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm fairly new with python/gui stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you need is to provide a `tuple` to your `padx` and/or `pady`.

You can specify padding for each side this way.

I use `pady` as an example here to show how you can provide padding on only one side. Notice how the top Label is padded at its top but the bottom button is not padded on the bottom side.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

DC1_path_label = Label(root, text = "Please specify the path of DC 1:", relief=RAISED)
DC1_B = Button(root)
DC2_path_label = Label(root, text="Please specify the path of DC 2:", relief=RAISED)
DC2_B = Button(root)

DC1_path_label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = (10, 0))
DC1_B.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = (10, 0))
DC2_path_label.grid(row = 3, column = 1, pady = (10, 0))
DC2_B.grid(row = 4, column = 1, pady = (10, 0))

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Update:

As far as changing your window there are several options for manipulating what is there and replacing the content.

You could `destroy()` the widgets and make new ones. Though this does not strike me as more elegant. It will allow you to keep the window open though.

There are some config options you can use to change the text of current widgets or rearrange the grid through a series of configs. Though this does not strike me as elegant either.

Comment: Thanks, those tuples for padx/pady work great.

Funny thing is, the GUI was missing elements if I put a about 18 or so on it... I could get the missing ones by commenting other elements out...

Regardless, your solution works fine with .pack too, and this doesn't miss gui elements, so I'll use that instead.